# How to print page exactly how it looks on screen?

Tags: css, asp.net, printing

I'm creating a scheduling page through ASP.NET Web Forms using custom CSS. I have added a print button and would like it to print the page exactly how it looks on screen, however it's seems to be ignoring all my CSS when I go to print. How can I fix this?

My schedule layout:

[image]

How it currently prints:

[image]

My CSS:

```
.board-layout {
    background-color: #173F5F;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 6px;
    padding: 6px;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    border-radius: 6px;
    overflow: auto;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 0 rgba(9,30,66,.25);
    border: 3px solid black;
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}

.board-layout:hover {
    /*transform: scale(1.005);*/
    border: 3px solid lightgrey;
}

.list-layout {
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 10px;
}

.board-text {
    font-size: 14px;
    padding: 6px;
    color: #EEFBFB;
}

.board-lists {
    display: grid;
    grid-auto-columns: 13.9%;
    grid-auto-flow: column;
    grid-gap: 6px;
    height: auto;
}
.crew-board-lists {
    display: grid;
    grid-auto-columns: 49.72%;
    grid-auto-flow: column;
    grid-gap: 6px;
    height: auto;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.Job-lists {
    display: grid;
    grid-auto-columns: auto;
    grid-auto-flow: column;
    grid-gap: 10px;
    height: auto;
}

.board-list {
    background-color: rgb(235, 236, 240);
    border-radius: 4px;
    display: grid;
    grid-auto-rows: max-content;
    grid-gap: 10px; /* Chrome use a fixed height */
    min-height: 40px;
    height: max-content;
    padding: 6px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.day-board-list {
    background-color: #EBEBEB;
    border-radius: 4px;
    display: grid;
    grid-auto-rows: max-content;
    grid-gap: 10px; /* Chrome use a fixed height */
    min-height: 40px;
    height: max-content;
    padding: 6px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.day-board-list:hover, .crew-board-list:hover, .equipment-board-list:hover, .card:hover, .cardEmployee:hover, .cardEquipment:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 14px 28px rgba(0,0,0,0.25), 0 10px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.22);
    transform: scale(1.01);
    border: 1px solid white;
}

.day-board-list, .crew-board-list, .equipment-board-list, .card, .cardEmployee, .cardEquipment {
    transition: all .1s ease-in-out;
}

.DragHoverCustom {
    box-shadow: 0 14px 28px rgba(0,0,0,0.25), 0 10px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.22);
    transform: scale(1.01);
    border: 1px solid white;
}

.date-list {
    background-color: #EBEBEB;
    border-radius: 4px;
    display: grid;
    grid-auto-rows: max-content;
    grid-gap: 10px; /* Chrome use a fixed height */
    height: auto;
    padding: 4px;
    text-align: center;
}

.crew-board-list {
    background-color: #3C99DC;
    border-radius: 4px;
    display: grid;
    grid-auto-rows: max-content;
    grid-gap: 10px; /* Chrome use a fixed height */
    height: max-content;
    min-height: 34px;
    padding: 6px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.equipment-board-list {
    background-color: #70D1D0;
    border-radius: 4px;
    display: grid;
    grid-auto-rows: max-content;
    grid-gap: 10px; /* Chrome use a fixed height */
    height: max-content;
    min-height: 34px;
    padding: 6px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.list-title {
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.schedule-dates {
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.card {
    background-color: #EEFBFB;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 0 rgba(9,30,66,.25);
    padding: 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.cardEquipment {
    background-color: #70D1D0;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 0 rgba(9,30,66,.25);
    padding: 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.cardEmployee {
    background-color: #3C99DC;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 0 rgba(9,30,66,.25);
    padding: 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.tabs {
    width: 100%;
    height: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

/* tab list item */
.tabs .tabs-list {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

.tabs .tabs-list li {
    width: 30%;
    float: left;
    margin: 0px;
    margin-right: 2px;
    padding: 10px 5px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #173F5F;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

.tabs .tabs-list li:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.tabs .tabs-list li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}

/* Tab content section */
.tabs .tab {
    display: none;
    width: 96%;
    min-height: 200px;
    height: auto;
    border-radius: 4px;
    padding: 20px 15px;
    background-color: #EBEBEB;
    clear: both;
}

.tabs .tab h3 {
    border-bottom: 3px solid cornflowerblue;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    font-weight: normal;
    padding: 5px;
}

.tabs .tab p {
    line-height: 20px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}

/* When active state */
.active {
    display: block !important;
}

.tabs .tabs-list li.active {
    background-color: #EBEBEB !important;
    color: black !important;
}

.active a {
    color: black !important;
}

/* media query */
@media screen and (max-width:360px) {
    .tabs {
        margin: 0;
        width: 96%;
    }

    .tabs .tabs-list li {
        width: 80px;
    }
}

/* Context menu */
.context-menu {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 3px;
    width: 200px;
    background: white;
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 10px black;
    z-index: 10000;
}

.context-menu ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 2px;
}

.context-menu ul li {
    padding: 5px 2px;
    margin-bottom: 3px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: darkturquoise;
}

.context-menu ul li:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #7fffd4;
}
```

Normal CSS link on my page:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Content/CustomCSS.css" type="text/css">
```

Comment: The only way *might* be to create a new `css` file called `print.css` which is auto-invoked on print. Sucks but might be the only way. I've done it. (See below.)

Comment: also background colors are printed only if you tell the printer to do so ... on the user side.  You also probably want a landscape print . set a print.css style sheet and call it via `@media print{@page {size: landscape} /*selector and  style here */}`

Comment: The output will never be exactly what you see on screen, because screens use different technologies than printers to show information, and you just can't have an exact 1:1 between them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution called [html2canvas](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/) which rebuilds any element or the entire page as an image. My JavaScript code ended up looking like this and produces a perfect copy of my schedule!

```
function customPrint() {
    document.getElementById('scheduleArea').style.maxHeight = 'max-content';
    html2canvas(document.querySelector("#scheduleArea")).then(canvas => {
        document.body.appendChild(canvas)
    }).then(() => {
        let canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
        canvas.style.display = 'none';
        let image = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
        let tWindow = window.open("");
        $(tWindow.document.body)
            .html("<img id='Image' src=" + image + " style='width:100%; height:auto;'></img>")
            .ready(function () {
                tWindow.focus();
                tWindow.print();
            });
        document.getElementById('scheduleArea').style.maxHeight = '800px';
        document.body.removeChild(canvas);
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Just checked, and what I actually did was added media styles:

```
@media print {
    *                           {   color:#333; }
    html                        {   height:auto; }
    h1:before                   {   content:"Site Name - "; }
    .pageTitle                  {   font-size:20pt; }
    #selectedTitleWrapper       {   text-align: left !important; }
    .mainContentColumn          {   margin-bottom: 0; }
}
```

These styles are used on print and override existing styles. Experiment with a few. For ex, remove the scroll bar in your top row:

```
.container { overflow-x: hidden; } /* for example. */
```